# DNN - How to Transfer Production Version Code in Local with enabling debug

Tags: dotnetnuke

I have downloaded DNN from production and copied in local server. and followed below steps to make it running in  local.

```
1. Copy DNN source to local
2. Created Virtual Directory in IIS 7 and created application as localhost/sitename
2. Changed Portal Alias in database to localhost/sitename
3. Changed Web.Config for Portal Alias
```

My code started working by doing above. But I am not able to debug code.

How can I make it to run in debug mode ? 
I am very new for DNN. Please help me on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debugging DotNetNuke Modules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/650818/debugging-dotnetnuke-modules)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to enable debugging in the web.config file.

After that, in Visual Studio open "website" and connect to that VirtualDirectory/application you configured.

That should allow you to debug some of the DNN code, but you may also want to install the SYMBOLS project from DNN (another download from codeplex) which provides the Debug symbols.

If you have custom modules, you'll want the symbols for those if you want to debug them as well.

Chris